# use select statement in oracle check constraint

Tags: oracle, select, constraints

Can we use select statement when we declare a check constraint

```
create table category
(id_category number primary key,
category varcahr2(100) check (category in (select * from table1))
```

thank you

Comment: You are actually looking for a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  If you are trying to verify that the `category` exists in `table1`, assuming that `category` is the primary key of `table1`, you'd want a foreign key constraint not a `check` constraint.  It would seem very odd, though, for there to be a `category` table where the `category` referenced a different parent table (presumably the `category` table defines the valid categories).  Perhaps you want to define a unique constraint to ensure that there aren't duplicate `category` values in the table.  Perhaps you're trying to do something else-- explaining the business problem will help us understand the proper way to model the issue.

Comment: I want just ask if we can use select statement when we use check constraint

Comment: @dba2015 - Then my first paragraph- "No, you can't" is the answer you're looking for.